# SQL (where in) returns no results

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle "table1"

```
number code
111    aaa
222    bbb
333    aaa
```

Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, CODE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NUMBER IN (
'444',
'111',
'333',
'222'
) GROUP BY CODE;
```

Answer

```
CNT CODE
2   aaa
1   bbb
```

Need result, please help.

```
CNT  CODE
1    null
2    aaa
1    bbb
```

I try request with "nvl" but it returns(count) only rows with (null) code, but not count rows.

PS. Sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT CODE, COUNT(t1.NUMBER) AS CNT
FROM (SELECT '444' as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '111' as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '333' as num FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '222' as num FROM DUAL 
     ) x LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1 t1
     ON t1.NUMBER = x.num
GROUP BY CODE;
```